# JavaScript regex remove any prefix on perfect match

Tags: javascript, regex

How can I remove "Dr", "Dr.", or "dr" in a string?

```
"Dr. Drake Cohen" would become "Drake Cohen"
"Dr Drake Cohen" would become "Drake Cohen"
"Drake Cohen" would become "Drake Cohen"
"Rachel Smith" would become "Rachel Smith"
"Dr. Rachel Smith" would become "Rachel Smith"
```

What I've tried:

```
str.replace(/dr./i, "")
```

but this removes all instances of Dr

Comment: `.replace(/^[dr\.]+ /gi, '')`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Go with this regex.

**Regex:** `dr[\.\s]` case insensitive should be ON.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k0GBTV/1)

[image]

---

From revo's comment this one is far better to avoid matching `dr` in names such as `Alexandr`.

**Regex:** `\bdr[.\s]\s?` This will check for `word boundary` before `dr`.

[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/k0GBTV/5)

Comment: Little improvement - `dr[\.\s]\s?`

Comment: @Kinduser: Is dr follwed by optional whitespace ?

Comment: @Kinduser `dr[\.\s]\s*` is better.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir Yeah, `*` is better.

Comment: Or even `dr[.\s]+` @ibrahimmahrir

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir: Thank you for the improvement.

Comment: @revo: No that will allow any character after `dr`.

Comment: @revo: `+` means _one or more_. Though it works in this case, logically it should not be used here. Character class is best choice here.

Comment: Then what do you call `[.\s]`? Isn't it a character class? `+` could be used since there should be always a space or a `.` following. @Rahul

Comment: @bobblebubble: I would say that `d` should always be capital since it's a salutation. But don't know what's in OP's text.

Comment: @revo: Also you are missing It's `\.` not `.`

Comment: `.` in a character class doesn't have a special meaning. It's a literal character. @Rahul

Comment: @revo: Oh. Thanks for correcting. Now I need to brush up regex.